# How to confirm CONFIG setting made with make menuconfig?

Tags: linux-kernel, configuration

I poke around `make menuconfig` select this, deselect that.  Rebuild a linux kernel and boot up with it.  How can I confirm the selection(s) I made via menuconfig exist after booting?  `lsmod`?

Comment: usually the config file is copied to /boot as /boot/config-`uname -r`. Do you have that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your distribution and kernel version the configuration of the currently running kernel can be in one of the following locations:

```
/proc/config.gz
/boot/config
/boot/config-$(uname -r)
```

The first one provides the proc filesystem and must be configured in the kernel config:

```
General Setup  --->
    <*> Kernel .config support
        [*] Enable access to .config through /proc/config.gz
```